# Django Rest Framework returning duplicate data when returning a nested json response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a pricing table that contains the following fields: `id`, `date`, `price_non_foil`, `price_foil`, `card_id`. This table holds pricing data for each card for each day. For Example:

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "23a6c413-7818-47a8-9bd9-6de7c328f103" | "2021-12-08" | 0.24 | 0.80 | "2ab9aecc-ce3c-4aaa-bf3c-fe9da4bba827" |
| "c51a72ab-f29f-4465-a210-ff38b15e83a1" | "2021-12-05" | 1.27 | 0.80 | "2ab9aecc-ce3c-4aaa-bf3c-fe9da4bba827" |
| "17289b71-3b73-4e16-a479-25a7069a142e" | "2021-12-09" | 0.38 | 0.80 | "2ab9aecc-ce3c-4aaa-bf3c-fe9da4bba827" |
| "fa88f619-ec32-4550-9a57-c77b6e1a8e11" | "2021-12-07" | 1.27 | 0.80 | "2ab9aecc-ce3c-4aaa-bf3c-fe9da4bba827" |
| "f996d6cb-7d98-415c-bd70-2fca8f4e03a5" | "2021-12-06" | 1.27 | 0.80 | "2ab9aecc-ce3c-4aaa-bf3c-fe9da4bba827" |
| "2f8c00f3-4d47-478d-a653-7d7a476e9bae" | "2021-12-09" | 0.43 | 3.33 | "2e5e1d78-0818-4ecd-a8f0-37e280aaa30a" |
| "15b20912-4103-4e08-8f91-fed820b761af" | "2021-12-05" | 0.66 | 5.08 | "2e5e1d78-0818-4ecd-a8f0-37e280aaa30a" |

Currently there is pricing data for 5 dates for each card. I am trying to create an endpoint to return the latest 2 prices for each card using Django rest framework. I have managed to get the response to be nest under the card id, but my issue is that it returns multiple card ids, I assume based on the number of pricing data records for each card.

**views.py**

```py
class individual_set_pricing(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SerializerSetsIndividualPricing

    def get_queryset(self):
        code = self.kwargs.get('code', None)
        qs = magic_sets_cards_pricing.objects.filter(card_id__set_id__code=code.upper()).values('card_id')
        return qs
```

**serializers.py**

```py
class SerializerSetsIndividualPricing(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    card = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_card')

    class Meta:
        model = magic_sets_cards_pricing
        fields = ['card_id', 'card']

    def get_card(self, obj):
        date = magic_sets_cards_pricing.objects.filter(card_id=obj['card_id']).values('date', 'price_non_foil', 'price_foil').order_by('-date')[:2]
        return date
```

**Response**

```json
[
    {
        "card_id": "3a261180-c1b3-4641-9524-956be55bee7a",
        "card": [
            {
                "date": "2021-12-09",
                "price_non_foil": 1.15,
                "price_foil": 1.54
            },
            {
                "date": "2021-12-08",
                "price_non_foil": 0.43,
                "price_foil": 1.62
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "card_id": "3a261180-c1b3-4641-9524-956be55bee7a",
        "card": [
            {
                "date": "2021-12-09",
                "price_non_foil": 1.15,
                "price_foil": 1.54
            },
            {
                "date": "2021-12-08",
                "price_non_foil": 0.43,
                "price_foil": 1.62
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
```

how to I remove the duplicate records in the json response?

Comment: What was causing the issue?